# Up-casting function pointers returning derived types in Fortran2018

Tags: fortran

Here's the example.

```
module example

  type scheme_object
  end type scheme_object

  type, extends( scheme_object ) :: scheme_primitive_procedure
     procedure(packageable_function), pointer, nopass :: proc_pointer
  end type scheme_primitive_procedure
  abstract interface
     function packageable_function() result( retval )
       import :: scheme_object
       class(scheme_object), pointer :: retval
     end function packageable_function
  end interface

contains

  recursive function make_primitive_procedure_object() result( retval_pointer )
    type(scheme_primitive_procedure), pointer :: retval
    class(scheme_object), pointer :: retval_pointer
    allocate( scheme_primitive_procedure :: retval )
    retval%proc_pointer => make_primitive_procedure_object
    retval_pointer => retval
  end function make_primitive_procedure_object

end module example
```

The MWE is slightly overcomplicated in the name of making the code shorter. Simply speaking, an instance of scheme_primitive_procedure should encapsulate functions returning various subtypes of scheme_object.

In the make_primitive_procedure_object the result type is a subtype of scheme_object, representing functions returning scheme objects.

What is wrong with this code? The problem is that I don't really want to only_ever return class(scheme_object)s from my procedures. I want my procedures to return pointers to various subtypes of scheme_object without explicit up-casting.

Is this possible?

Comment: I'm not clear on what you are asking - there's no "explicit upcasting" (as I'd consider it) in your example.  I suspect you are asking if the target procedure on the right of a pointer assignment statement involving procedures can have different characteristics (namely the declared type of the function result) than the interface of the object on the left hand side.  Perhaps show an example of what you want to do.

Comment: The last line in the make_primitive_procedure_object casts type(scheme_primitive_procedure) retval  to class(scheme_object) retval_pointer.  I don't want to do that in every function I write. I want to just return retvals, which would be subtypes of scheme_object

Comment: There is no "select type", because "select type" can only cast types _down_ the inheritance hierarchy, not up. But it is allowed to assign a derived type pointer value to a parent type pointer.

Comment: There's no parent component reference either, which is what I consider *explicit* upcasting.

Comment: I am sorry if I used wrong terms. I just mean that retval_pointer is declared as class(scheme_object), pointer :: retval_pointer, which _is_ a parent type. I don't want to do that in every procedure.

Answer (score 0):

If a procedure pointer object has an explicit interface (which is required for procedure pointer objects that have polymorphic arguments, amongst many other things - F2018 15.4.2.2p1), then the characteristics of the target procedure must match (bar pureness) - 10.2.2.4p3).  The characteristics of a procedure that is a function include the declared type of the function result (15.3.1p1/15.3.3p1).

The declared type of the function result of the procedure must match the declared type of the function result of the procedure pointer.

Comment: So there is no notion of _compatible_ pointers to procedures? Pointer types have to either completely match or not match at all? It is also not possible to assign a procedure ("address") to a class(*) pointer?

Comment: There is no notion of compatible pointers to procedures.  CLASS(*) is for data entities, procedures are not data entities.

Comment: I'll accept your answer if you add a note about non-compatibility of pointers.